# Is it possible to only specify the name of the "base.html" file in the {%extends%}, instead of "app/base.html"?

Tags: python-3.x, django, path, django-templates

I'm learning Django and I stumble upon a question:
Is it possible to make the path to the *base.html* file in the *{% extends "app/base.html" %}* link from the *helloworld.html* file as short as possible?
So I would only have to write *{% extends "base.html" %}* to make it work.

Right now, if I try to do this, python will throw an exception at the *def helloworld(request)*: function in *views.py*.

So my app file structure is:

```
├── app
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── static
│   ├── templates 
│      ├── app
│         ├── base.html
│         ├── helloworld.html
│   ├── views.py 
│   └── models.py 
├── DjangoProject
│   ├── __init__.py 
│   ├── urls.py 
│   ├── settings.py 
│   ├── templates 
├── manage.py
```

helloworld.html:

```
{% extends "app/base.html" %}

{% block head_title %} hello {% endblock %}

{% block content %} 
<p> hello world </p> 
{% endblock %}
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpRequest

def helloworld(request):
    hello_title = 'Test'
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    return render(
        request,
        'app/helloworld.html',
        {
            'title_test':hello_title    
        }
    )
```

settings.py:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'app',]
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates'),],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I have tried including another path into the *'DIRS:'* section the *TEMPLATES* in the *settings.py* file but it doesn't seem to work.
The django documentation and another stackoverflow post I have found only talk about adding the "app/base.html" path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, you can send it from your view by simply using `{% extends template_name %}`

And in your view:

```
return render(
    request,
    'app/helloworld.html',
    {
        'title_test': hello_title,
        'template_name': 'app/base.html'
    }
)
```

Keep in mind, this will not use the title you gave in the render.
For it to use the title, it needs to have a variable in the template with that name.
`{% block head_title %} {{ title_test }} {% endblock %}`

Personally, the way I do it is by having the app name in a different variable, like for example:

```
class MyView(View):
    template_name = f'{APP_NAME}/{TEMPLATE_NAME}'
    ...
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
        return render(
            request,
            'app/helloworld.html',
            {
                'title_test': hello_title,
                'template_name': self.template_name
            }
        )
```

Both variables being constants I import from a different file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it is very clear.


Can you also tell me if adding another path pointing directly at the last 'app/' file into  'DIR' in the 'TEMPLATES' section of the settings.py file would be enough to make the {% extends base.html %} working?


I don't understand why my path pointing directly to the 'app/' file isn't working while it works if it points to its parent file 'templates/'?

Comment: @LeBruceWayne Don't quite understand what you mean by that. You shouldn't really touch the `TEMPLATES` variable in settings unless you have some unique settings. `'DIRS'` should remain `[]` unless you have the template directory somewhere else other than `templates` in each app directory. `APP_DIRS` should also remain `True`.

Comment: The way the template pathing is built by default is `project/app/templates/`. Any folder in `templates` will need to be written when you extend or include.